# Function returns NaN when page loaded, but on change/update works correctly, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript

When I load the page I want to run the **cadConvert()** function so it computes the value of BTC set by the slider based of the CAD value but it only does so when I change/update the value of cad or move the slider...

I want it to show the BTC equivalent when it loads instead of saying 'NaN', it only works as desired when I assign the variable **price** a static integer instead of the dynamic one I am pulling from bitcoinaverage's api.

https://jsfiddle.net/7b2jaLxh/12/

```
 var directionSlider = document.getElementById('slider-direction');

 noUiSlider.create(directionSlider, {
   start: 20,
   connect: [true, false],
   direction: 'ltr',
   range: {
     'min': 2,
     'max': 99.99
   }
 });
 var price;
 var cadc = document.getElementById('cadc');
 var btcc = document.getElementById('btcc');

 directionSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
   cadc.value = directionSlider.noUiSlider.get();
   cadConvert();
 });

 cadc.addEventListener('change', function() {
   directionSlider.noUiSlider.set(this.value);
   cadConvert();
 });
 btcc.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
   directionSlider.noUiSlider.set(this.value * price);
   cadConvert();

 });

 function cadConvert() {
   var cad = parseFloat(directionSlider.noUiSlider.get());
   var cadCalc = cad / price;
   document.getElementById("btcc").value = cadCalc;

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your jsfiddle: Why don't you call cadConvert in this js? Basically just wait for the data then then run all your javascript code. That way, price will be defined after the data is retrieved.

```
var xbtc = new XMLHttpRequest();
xbtc.open('GET', 'https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/global/CAD/', true);
xbtc.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xbtc.readyState == 4){
        var ticker = JSON.parse(xbtc.responseText);
        price = ticker.last;
        document.getElementById('btc').innerHTML = "Global Market: $" + (price).toFixed(2) + " CAD";
        cadConvert();
    }
};
xbtc.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are having this problem is that `price` is not initially defined! it is a good practice to always initialize varibales!
Line 27 you can set the price to the default value of `directionSlider`
`var price = directionSlider.noUiSlider.get();`

https://jsfiddle.net/wt0asmqe/